# How can I click a plotly mode bar button using JS in shiny?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs

I've gathered that I need to use shinyjs and extendShinyjs, so here's what I have so far:

in ui.R outside of the ui function:

```
js_reset_axes <- "shinyjs.reset_axes = function(){ }"
```

inside the ui function:

```
extendShinyjs(text = js_reset_axes, functions = c("reset_axes"))
```

and in the server function:

```
js$reset_axes()
```

I don't really know js syntax, but I know I have to fill the ui.R function with the mode bar button location and indicate I want it clicked. I gather this is the location for the reset axes button:

```
<a rel="tooltip" class="modebar-btn" data-title="Reset axes" data-attr="zoom" data-val="reset" data-toggle="false" data-gravity="n">
```

What's the correct js syntax to have it clicked?

There are multiple elements with the same `classname` so I'd have to specify using the `data-title` or `data-val` identifier. Alternatively, it is possible to remove all other elements and just leave the one I'm interested in using.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest this, since you want to select the fouth element with a classname : `.modebar-btn`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.modebar-btn')[3].click();
```